# Changing the action of Wordpress form issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I changed the action in the search form of the Wordpress default page search to a custom page and template I created :

`<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://localhost/wordpress/restaurants">`

When I try to submit the form the link changes to this : `http://localhost/wordpress/restaurants/?s=test` and instead of displaying the page I linked to it tells me that the page is not found.

With the `a` or `h` or `e` (for some weird reason only this letters) keyword it works as expect.

Why this is happening?

Comment: You're using `GET` with an input that has `name="s"`...it sounds like things are working how they've been defined. What do you want to happen?

Comment: @rnevius The page which display the result is the default page of search of wordpress even thought the link tells the opposite while I want to use my specified page, it only appear when I use a as keyword.

Comment: I've added an update hope it is cleared now

Comment: can you post the code after the <form> tag? In other words the form itself

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mw5rAvze . I don't really think this a problem from the form declaration I think it's some permalinks issue or htaccess issue